# Is It Possible To Shorten This Code? Pygame-

Tags: python, pygame

I have a bunch of different bullets with different list and I wondering if I could shorten the way of doing this without copying and pasting and making thousands of lines of code.

the code is checking if  all those bullets list are collided with the enemy sprite

is there way I could put a list in a list or something so I dont have to write all these code
for example
I have

```
bullet1 = []
bullet2 = []
bullet3 = []
# and store all those bullet in another list?
all_bullets = [bullet1,bullet2,bullet3] is that possibale?
```

```
def upgrade_tower_1():
    if upgrade1.x == 9000:
        collid_1 = False
        for monster in monsters:
            for shootss in shootsright:
                if monster.rect.colliderect(shootss.rect):
                    collid_1 = False
                    monster.direction = "hit"
                    if monster.health > 2:
                        monster.health -= 0.2
                    else:
                        monster.x = void.x + 20 
                        monster.y = void.y + 150
                        money1.cash += 5


    if upgrade5.x == 9000:
        collid_1 = False
        for monster in monsters:
            for shootss in shootsright:
                if monster.rect.colliderect(shootss.rect):
                    collid_1 = False
                    monster.direction = "hit"
                    if monster.health > 2:
                        monster.health -= 0.3
                    else:
                        monster.x = void.x + 20 
                        monster.y = void.y + 150
                        money1.cash += 5




    if upgrade5.x == 9000:
        collid_1 = False
        for monster in monsters:
            for shootss2 in shootsright2:
                if monster.rect.colliderect(shootss2.rect):
                    collid_1 = False
                    monster.direction = "hit"
                    if monster.health > 2:
                        monster.health -= 0.3
                    else:
                        monster.x = void.x + 20 
                        monster.y = void.y + 150
                        money1.cash += 5
```

Comment: What is the reason for `upgrade_time = 100` `if upgrade_time >= 100:`. I mean why do you check `upgrade_time >= 100` when you set `upgrade_time = 100` in the line before?

Comment: I dont really that but I forgot to remove it my bad

Comment: Why is `collid_1` always `False`?

Comment: its false because when I upgrade I stop my bullets from damaging 0.1 to my enemys and then it will start doing the damage 0.2

Comment: It doesn't make sens to set `collid_1 = False` before the loop and again `collid_1 = False` in the loop. It will never become `True`

Comment: Code that works but is just too long is not on-topic here -- it's a good fit for our sister site [codereview.se], though. Stack Overflow is only for code that has a _specific problem_, where you've already done the work to build the shortest possible reproducer for that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to write a function (or a method) that tests for collisions between `shootsright` and `monsters`:

```py
def detect_collision(monsterlist, shootlist, money):
    collide = False
    for monster in monsterlist:
        for shootss in shootlist:
            if monster.rect.colliderect(shootss.rect):
                collide = False # True ?
                monster.direction = "hit"
                if monster.health > 2:
                    monster.health -= 0.2
                else:
                    monster.x = void.x + 20 
                    monster.y = void.y + 150
                    money.cash += 5
    return collide
```

Instead of duplicating the code, call the function:

```py
if upgrade1.x == 9000:
    collid_1 = detect_collision(monsters, shootsright, money1)

# [...]

if upgrade5.x == 9000:
    collid_1 = detect_collision(monsters, shootsright, money1)

# [...]

if upgrade5.x == 9000:
    collid_1 = detect_collision(monsters, shootsright2, money1)

# [...]
```

Comment: wouldnt  I need to make another detect collisions for my  other shootss2 shootss3 and there list shootsright2 shootsright3 I have a lot of shootsright2 and 3..5.6 those are for each of my bullet list

Comment: also is there way I could change it where it says monster.rect.collid and the parts for shootss and shoosright so we can put what ever on it later when we call it on the detect(collisions(monsters,shootsright,money1)  and also if we had another monster we could say detect(collisions(rabbit,shootsright2,money1) because I have defferent monster and defferent list

Comment: Yes you can. May be you want to read [Python Functions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp).

Comment: I am sorry if your shocked this is still new to me and I havent done it before thanks for teaching me I am

Comment: ok I get the concept and I am trying it for my moving bullets I defined a new [function IMAGE](https://gyazo.com/fac1a1a7acced7083b63dc9e27499c61) then I called it in my main looop like this [IMAGE] (https://gyazo.com/c918ca2b0baf311822d267fd54fcf98e) but I keep getting an error 'shootss is not defined' even tho I defined it when I called it on my main loop sorry to bother you one more time..

Comment: @HabibIsmail No you didn't get the concept. The function just needs 3 arguments: `def detect_collision(monsterlist, shootlist, money):`- Please follow the suggestions in my answer. You don't need the arguments `shootss` and `monster`. `monster` and `shootss` are elements of the lists. You get the elements form the list in the function.